# How to create an express api executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have created a fully functioning fairly basic javaScript Node.js Express API application that I want to run as an executable in a windows environment.  I am wanting to do this so I can give clients the ability to run my API on premise without exposing my source code to them.

Currently I have been using the [pkg npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) which allows me to package my node.js application into an executable that will contain everything needed to run the app including node and my bundled source code.

My executable runs but my POST route is breaking with the following error:

```
    "name": "RequestError",
    "message": "Error: form-data: File or directory 'C:\\**\\myapp-api\\uploads\\1553103249524_test.wav' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.",
    "cause": {
        "errno": -4058,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "path": "C:\\snapshot\\myapp-api\\uploads\\test.wav",
        "pkg": true
    },
    "error": {
        "errno": -4058,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "path": "C:\\snapshot\\myapp-api\\uploads\\1553103249524_test.wav",
        "pkg": true
    },
```

My POST allows clients to upload a file in a multipart form using [multer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to another external API that will return some metadata.  pkg.js doesn't appear to have the means to discover files that are included after the bundling of the executable.

Is there anything I can do in my configuration for my uploaded files to be included?  Is there some other utility or process that others use for creating an executable of their node.js express APIs that would better handle the issue I am having?

Any guidance would really be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your files under "assets" in the package.json file.

The config paragraph on the pkg website https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#config states:

> So you must specify the files - scripts and assets - manually in pkg property of your package.json file.

```
"pkg": {
    "scripts": "build/**/*.js",
    "assets": "views/**/*"
}
```

> You may also specify arrays of globs:

```
"assets": [ "assets/**/*", "images/**/*" ]
```

> Just be sure to call pkg package.json or pkg . to make use of scripts and assets entries.

Comment: So my project doesn't have an `assets/..` or `scripts/..` folder.  I have attempted to use something like this  `"pkg": { "uploads/**/*}` right?  I am still having this same issue using this.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using something like this in your script (I am guessing since you didnt provide this part of the code)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/uploads'));
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/uploads'));
```

__dirname will be wrong when you pack your .exe get rid of it everywhere and replace it with ./

```
app.use(express.static('./uploads'));

res.sendFile(path.join('./uploads'));
```

Something like that. It worked for me.

Good luck!